# How to share fabcar data between two different blockchain(Hyperledger Fabric) running on different machines?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have successfully implemented the Hyperledger Fabric blockchain locally and able to successfully query the Fabcar eample. Now I want to deploy two instance of the same(Hyperledger Fabric) on two different machines in such a way that they share the common blockchain. If information of Fabcar is updated on one machine it get updated on the second one two.

Any help on the same will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to install Hyperledger Fabric on distributed computers, run the peer executable on each and make them join same channel and share configuration allowing to connect to the ordering service. Here a few side project which could help you to span Hyperledger Fabric distributed network:

1. [Hyperledger Fabric deployment script](https://github.com/yacovm/fabricDeployment)
2. [Ansible plybooks](https://github.com/litong01/fabric-deploy)

Once you will have your network running all you need is to install chaincode on each remote peer, create a channel, join remote peers to the channel and instantiate the chaincode. Of course in terms of fabcar example you will have to update all IP addresses and rest of the config parameters to suit your environment and network configuration.

Comment: If we want to achieve same using hyperledger composer, then we have to deploy same bna on each peer?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not a composer expert, so not really able to provide you with good answer :/